# django-simple-captcha Don't work when DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, recaptcha, django-cms

I'm working on Django 2.2 and DjangoCMS 3.7.4 I'm facing a problem with django-simple-captacha I've follow the installation guide (https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#installation)

It's working when `DEBUG=True` but when `DEBUG=False` in `settings.py` I got a 500 on when I try to send a contact form.

Here my `urls.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.views.static import serve
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .views import career_form, contact_form, mentions

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^mentions/$', mentions, name='mentions'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap,
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),  # NOQA
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^career/', include('career.urls')),
    url(r'^carreer_form', career_form, name='career_form'),
    url(r'^contact_form', contact_form, name='contact_form'),
)

urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        ] + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns
```

My installed app in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'filer',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_snippet',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_video',
    'absolute',
    'aldryn_forms',
    'aldryn_forms.contrib.email_notifications',
    'captcha',
    'emailit',
    'macros',
    'oloron',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'logs.apps.LogsConfig',
    'charts.apps.ChartsConfig',
    'directory.apps.DirectoryConfig',
    'career.apps.CareerConfig',
    'accordion'
]
```

Comment: Well considering it is a captcha I assume it uses static / media files? Django _does not_ serve static / media files in production (When `Debug=False`) because it is inefficient. See [Deploying static files (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/) for information on serving static files in production.

Comment: How do you run your Django app when `DEBUG = False`? Are you still running locally with `./manage.py runserver`? Or are you running on a server? If you are still running locally, then check the output in the console that shows the entire stack trace. If you are running on a server, check the server logs for the stack trace.